# How can you show an MCBrowserViewController on a scene in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, bluetooth, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I'm porting a code to ios7 in wich I used old GKPeerPickerController and cocos2d to make a multiplayer game over Bluetooth. 
In the new version, I'm using the MCBrowserViewController, but im unable to show it on the scene.

Im calling it with

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview: browserVC];
```

where browserVC is an initiallized MCBrowserViewController but as this is only to show UIViews I get the error

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIView *' with an rvalue of
>   type 'MCBrowserViewController *'

Is there any way to show the MCBrowserViewController on the scene?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:browserVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Indeed it works!! Thanks for the fast response! I'll mark it as good as soon as SO lets me (in 6 minutes time)